# char array value not being changed to upper case

Tags: java, arrays, string, character, uppercase

I am writing a program that recieves a String as input and changes the format of the lettering if it contains an underscore. For example, if I receive the String "here_wego", it should return "hereWego", but instead of that I just get "herewego". What I have tried to do here is converting the incoming string to a character array and then check each character to check if it's an underscore. If it *isn't* an underscore, then the character gets added to the output string. If it *is* an underscore, the character is not added and instead c[i+1] should be changed to uppercase so it can be added in the next iterator.

```
public static String zebulansNightmare(final String functionName) {

    String manip = "";
    char[] c = functionName.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        if(c[i]!='_'){
            manip += c[i];
        } else {
            Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);
        }
    }

    return manip;
}
```

I've included a link to a picture of the debugging process.

[Going through the program debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NCfz.png)

Comment: `Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);` doesn't actually change `c[i+1]`: it simply returns the uppercased `char`. Also, changing a `char[]` which resulted from a call to `String.toCharArray()` doesn't change the string. You'd need to `return new String(c);`.

Comment: `char` is a primitive - this makes it immutable. `Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1])` returns a new `char` that is the uppercased version of the the `char` passed in - you discard this.

Comment: @AndyTurner I believe the OP wants to change some_snake_case_string into An Upper Cased String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    c[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
} else {
           manip += Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);
           i++;
        }
```

instead of

```
} else {
           Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not optimalized.

```
public static String zebulansNightmare(final String functionName) {

    String manip = "";
    char[] c = functionName.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        if (c[i] != '_'){
            manip += c[i];
        } else {
            i++;
            manip += Character.toUpperCase(c[i]);
        }
    }
    return manip;
}
```

See that i count `i++;` before i do the `c[i+1];`. Also the `manip +=` is used to add the char in upper case!

If you don't use the `i++;` , but instead you only use the `c[i+1]` Your outpur would be: **hereWwego**, instead of **hereWego**

Answer (score 0):

@AndyTurner, thanks I didn't realize that it just returned the character in an uppercase. I changed my code accordingly and fixed it:

```
if(c[i]!='_'){
            manip += c[i];
        } else {
            manip += Character.toUpperCase(c[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
```

Now I get the correct output, though it would throw an exception if the String was "here_"